# keras evaluate() using best model not last model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm training my model using **ModelCheckpoint** `save_best_only=True` and **EarlyStopping** `patience=5`. I use my test data for validation. When applying `evaluate()` using the same test data and the same callbacks, I get the same metrics as the last epoch model's `val_` metrics, not the "best model" ones. How can I use `evaluate()` and get my best model's metrics? I want to use `evaluate()` on out-of-time data to get these metrics for comparison and need to make sure it is using the best model.

`model.fit(x_train, y_train, callbacks=[stopper, checkpoint], validation_data=(x_test, y_test))`

`model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, callbacks=[stopper, checkpoint])`

expect metrics from epoch 4, but get metrics from epoch 9

Comment: As you are using the same data for validation while training the model and as test_data for model evaluation, then the trained model will show the same metrics values as val metrics. Please elaborate more on "best model" metrics.

Answer (score 0):

After training, you need to load the `best_model` and then evaluate it. Also I'm not sure if you need the callbacks in `model.evaluate()`.
So code could be something like this,

```py
# callback to save the best model
checkpoint_path = 'best_model.h5'
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                save_best_only=True)
# train
model.fit(x_train, 
          y_train,
          callbacks=[stopper, checkpoint],
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

# load best model
model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)

# evaluate
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```